# Changing Reference Colour to Black

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am new to LaTeX and I managed to add references to a document with `natbib` however when I preview it, the reference colour in the brackets appears to be in green colour. Everything else is fine. Would it still be green when I print it out? Or is this just a convenient built-in feature? How can I make it into black either way if I find this annoying? I am attaching a picture to show u what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Try `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` in your preamble.

Comment: Can't work out whether or not the "thank you so much" comment is joking. As much as I dislike ms word, and like LaTeX, arcane settings from [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) are not exactly intuitive -- unless you spend far too much time on this site! :)

Comment: If you want to keep other colors, the more specific option `citecolor` is what you want to change. See the `hyperref` manual, section 3, for more information. I like to just make the colors darker this way; the color-coding does help me. If you make the colors dark enough, they won't be easily-noticed when printed.